# Can you create a function that find the net quantity from buyer and seller columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have a dataset with many columns. The dataset contains `Seller_ID` and `Buyer_ID` and their quantity.

What I would like to do is to create a `net_ quantity`  column and a separate list. I am unsure how to execute the code.

Here is an example of the data.

[image: Here are an example of the data.]

See below for the result I would like to achieve. Buyer should be marked as `+` quantity and seller as `-` quantity. However, I also want to create a `net_ quantity`  column for the `ID` that are in both in the buyer and seller columns. Therefore, the column can be in the same dataframe

[image: See below for the result I would like to achieve. Buyer should be marked as + quantity and seller as - quantity. However, I also want to have a net_ quantity column for the ID that are in both in the buyer and seller columns. Therefore, the column can be in the same dataframe]

The column should look like this. Since it could be a situation where the ID is either in the buyer or seller list should they be marked as NULL. I also want to create a seperate list with all the  net_quantities since it´s going to be longer.

[image: The column should look like this. Since it could be a situation where the ID is either in the buyer or seller list should they be marked as NULL. I also want to create a seperate list with all the net_quantities since it´s going to be longer.]

The list I want to create

[image: The list I want to create]

Comment: Do you have code, that you could post? That would make it a lot easier to help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note:* You have a typo in the column name `"Quanity"` (it should be `"Quantity"`) but I'll respect it.

You may use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd        # pip install pandas

df = pd.read_excel("example.xlsx", "Sheet1")    

df_buyer  = df[["Buyer_lD",  "Quanity"]].set_index("Buyer_lD")
df_seller = df[["Seller_lD", "Quanity"]].set_index("Seller_lD")

df_joined = df_seller.join(df_buyer, how="outer", lsuffix="_s", rsuffix="_b").fillna(0)
df_joined["Diff"] = df_joined.Quanity_s - df_joined.Quanity_b

df_result = df_joined.Diff.reset_index()
df_result.columns = ["ID", "Quanity"]
```

---

**The detailed explanation:**

Here is your table after reading it from Excel (`df = pd.read_excel("example.xlsx", "Sheet1")`):

```
In[1]: df
```

> ```
>     Buyer_lD  Seller_lD  Quanity
> 0       1234       1242       14
> 1       1235       1241       23
> 2       1236       1240       32
> 3       1237       1239       41
> 4       1238       1238       50
> 5       1239       1237       59
> 6       1240       1236       68
> 7       1241       1235       77
> 8       1242       1234       86
> 9      13415     121434       95
> 10   1425526    1536346      104
> 11     15135    1561513      113
> ```

Now we'll create *two* tables — one for *buyers,* the second one for *sellers.*

The reason for it is *to be later able to align buyers IDs with sellers IDs* for performing an *appropriate* subtract (-) vectorized operation.

Creating of the first table I'll show in details, the second one I'll create in one-line command:

```
In[2]: df_buyer = df[["Buyer_lD", "Quanity"]]
In[3]: df_buyer
```

> ```
>     Buyer_lD  Quanity
> 0       1234       14
> 1       1235       23
> 2       1236       32
> 3       1237       41
> 4       1238       50
> 5       1239       59
> 6       1240       68
> 7       1241       77
> 8       1242       86
> 9      13415       95
> 10   1425526      104
> 11     15135      113
> ```

Now we replace the (default) index with the column `Buyer_lD`:

```
In[4]: df_buyer = df_buyer.set_index("Buyer_lD")
In[5]: df_buyer
```

> ```
>           Quanity
> Buyer_lD         
> 1234           14
> 1235           23
> 1236           32
> 1237           41
> 1238           50
> 1239           59
> 1240           68
> 1241           77
> 1242           86
> 13415          95
> 1425526       104
> 15135         113
> ```

Now the same as one command for the table of sellers:

```
In[6]: df_seller = df[["Seller_lD", "Quanity"]].set_index("Seller_lD")
In[7]: df_seller
```

> ```
>            Quanity
> Seller_lD         
> 1242            14
> 1241            23
> 1240            32
> 1239            41
> 1238            50
> 1237            59
> 1236            68
> 1235            77
> 1234            86
> 121434          95
> 1536346        104
> 1561513        113
> ```

We have 2 new tables, let's join them by index.

- We want to include all rows from both tables (“outer” joining).
- We want add the suffixes "_sold" and "_buyed " to the column names because there is the same column name ("Quanity") in both tables.

```
In[8]: df_joined = df_seller.join(df_buyer, how="outer", lsuffix="_sold", rsuffix="_buyed")
In[9]: df_joined
```

> ```
>          Quanity_sold  Quanity_buyed
> 1234             86.0           14.0
> 1235             77.0           23.0
> 1236             68.0           32.0
> 1237             59.0           41.0
> 1238             50.0           50.0
> 1239             41.0           59.0
> 1240             32.0           68.0
> 1241             23.0           77.0
> 1242             14.0           86.0
> 13415             NaN           95.0
> 15135             NaN          113.0
> 121434           95.0            NaN
> 1425526           NaN          104.0
> 1536346         104.0            NaN
> 1561513         113.0            NaN
> ```

There are `NaN` values — let's fill them with zeroes:

```
In[10]: df_joined = df_joined.fillna(0)
In[11]: df_joined
```

> ```
>          Quanity_sold  Quanity_buyed
> 1234             86.0           14.0
> 1235             77.0           23.0
> 1236             68.0           32.0
> 1237             59.0           41.0
> 1238             50.0           50.0
> 1239             41.0           59.0
> 1240             32.0           68.0
> 1241             23.0           77.0
> 1242             14.0           86.0
> 13415             0.0           95.0
> 15135             0.0          113.0
> 121434           95.0            0.0
> 1425526           0.0          104.0
> 1536346         104.0            0.0
> 1561513         113.0            0.0
> ```

Now there is no problem to append a column with differences:

```
In[12]: df_joined["Diff"] = df_joined.Quanity - df_joined.Quanity_buyer
In[13]: df_joined
```

> ```
>          Quanity_sold  Quanity_buyed   Diff
> 1234             86.0           14.0   72.0
> 1235             77.0           23.0   54.0
> 1236             68.0           32.0   36.0
> 1237             59.0           41.0   18.0
> 1238             50.0           50.0    0.0
> 1239             41.0           59.0  -18.0
> 1240             32.0           68.0  -36.0
> 1241             23.0           77.0  -54.0
> 1242             14.0           86.0  -72.0
> 13415             0.0           95.0  -95.0
> 15135             0.0          113.0 -113.0
> 121434           95.0            0.0   95.0
> 1425526           0.0          104.0 -104.0
> 1536346         104.0            0.0  104.0
> 1561513         113.0            0.0  113.0
> ```

and keep only the `"Diff"` column (this intermediate result will be a *series* with the name `"Diff"`):

```
In[14]: df_result = df_joined.Diff
In[15]: df_result
```

> ```
> 1234        72.0
> 1235        54.0
> 1236        36.0
> 1237        18.0
> 1238         0.0
> 1239       -18.0
> 1240       -36.0
> 1241       -54.0
> 1242       -72.0
> 13415      -95.0
> 15135     -113.0
> 121434      95.0
> 1425526   -104.0
> 1536346    104.0
> 1561513    113.0
> Name: Diff, dtype: float64
> ```

To finish the resulting table, we will reset index:

```
In[16]: df_result = df_result.reset_index()

In[17]: df_result
Out[17]:
```

> ```
>       index   Diff
> 0      1234   72.0
> 1      1235   54.0
> 2      1236   36.0
> 3      1237   18.0
> 4      1238    0.0
> 5      1239  -18.0
> 6      1240  -36.0
> 7      1241  -54.0
> 8      1242  -72.0
> 9     13415  -95.0
> 10    15135 -113.0
> 11   121434   95.0
> 12  1425526 -104.0
> 13  1536346  104.0
> 14  1561513  113.0
> ```

and rename columns:

```
In[18]: df_result.columns = ["ID", "Quanity"]

In[19]: df_result
Out[19]:
```

> ```
>          ID   Quanity
> 0      1234      72.0
> 1      1235      54.0
> 2      1236      36.0
> 3      1237      18.0
> 4      1238       0.0
> 5      1239     -18.0
> 6      1240     -36.0
> 7      1241     -54.0
> 8      1242     -72.0
> 9     13415     -95.0
> 10    15135    -113.0
> 11   121434      95.0
> 12  1425526    -104.0
> 13  1536346     104.0
> 14  1561513     113.0
> ```

and — if you wish it — change the last column type to `int`:

```
In[20]: df_result.Quanity = df_result.Quanity.astype(int)
In[21]: df_result
```

> ```
>          ID  Quanity
> 0      1234       72
> 1      1235       54
> 2      1236       36
> 3      1237       18
> 4      1238        0
> 5      1239      -18
> 6      1240      -36
> 7      1241      -54
> 8      1242      -72
> 9     13415      -95
> 10    15135     -113
> 11   121434       95
> 12  1425526     -104
> 13  1536346      104
> 14  1561513      113
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, works great! Glad somebody understood my poor written question.

Comment: You're welcome. You question wasn't poorly written, I understood it well. To the contrary I don't understand why they closed it as “opinion based” (I will vote for reopening it) and why so many people vote it down.